# Is it possible to identify every separate computer?

Tags: php, authentication, identity

I am thinking of a very simple log in system that doesn't require a login, but instead a system with an id and store it in a database. Then when the user comes back to the website he gets matched with his unique ID and logged-in in that way.

I am trying to do this with php as much as possible, initially I wanted to do it by using the IP address but as some people pointed out, places such as campuses share the same IP for many, many users.

So is there any way to uniquely identify each computer without using cookies, sessions or anything else that is client-side. Preferably with php.

Comment: Is it possible to somehow do it with MAC addresses?

Comment: Unless you wish to implement a physical executional on the clients machine to report the MAC Address to your remote server. Chances of obtaining the MAC is impossible with PHP

Comment: If you can get a machine to send its mac address, but that's outside of direct access from PHP

Comment: What happens when someone spills a coffee over their laptop and blow it up?

Comment: No. You can within a given margin of error looking at the accepts header and some other things, but someone installs or uninstalls something and it goes poof. Let's note, this is *terrible* from a security point of view and should be avoided altogether.

Comment: What about *LDAP* and family? I'm not a fan, but it's exactly what you want: loginless authentication.

Comment: @Marty I'm pretty sure, it'll perform some "boost" to the laptops performance, essentially overclocking the machine for a period of time before everything decides to go unresponsive

Comment: @Rudie - LDAP (and Active Directory) are not *loginless authentication*. Shibboleth and NTLM would be, though, but is not what the OP is looking for, I am sure, due to it's intrinsic networked requirements. OAuth might help, but, *ahem*, requires cookies.

Comment: @JaredFarrish LDAP isn't loginless? Or isn't authentication? I thought it was both... Shibboleth is one of many SSO services, isn't it?

Comment: @Rudie - LDAP is a directory structure and access that, to use from a given user's context, *requires* authentication. Active Directory stores properties that could be used to identify a machine within a network, but is itself reliant on different requirements like IP address to match identity (and isn't inherently tied to a user). You're talking about federated identity systems, where the user's credentials are matched to a session and shared among a network of servers. These are not the same concepts.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I don't see the difference between LDAP and Shibboleth (both provide SSO, so require auth somewhere in the process), but I don't know enough about either, so I believe you.

Comment: Even if it were possible to uniquely identify specific computers, having a login system based entirely on that would be a terrible idea. Not all people always use the same computer, and not all computers are used by only one person.

Comment: @duskwuff - Pointing out such trivialities resulted in the comment in my answer below (see the edit history).

Comment: @JaredFarrish Oh it is not for security, it is just for convenience. From a security point of view, it is one of the worst things I could do but in this specific scenario security does not matter that much.

Comment: Well, [here's more information](http://referaat.cs.utwente.nl/conference/16/paper/7306/using-browser-properties-for-fingerprinting-purposes.pdf) (and [W3's take on fingerprinting in a privacy context](https://www.w3.org/2014/strint/papers/41.pdf)) if you're willing to go down that route. You're looking for *passive fingerprinting*. There's also more information if you search for variations of *identifying browser by http header filetype:pdf*.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I do not want to identify the browser but the computer since some people use multiple browsers.

Comment: Read the papers. You're going to have to deduce if what you want is gettable using those techniques. Just be aware that identifying a request is coming from a *specific computer* is something of a holy grail in identify sniffing (see marketing and advertising, as well as other related fields). Companies have spent billions of dollars creating means for accomplishing this, and is something of Facebook's and Google's value proposition.

Comment: @JaredFarrish The first is talking about identification by browser (which I do not want) while the second is interesting nonetheless but does not give any usable methods for this context. Edit: And for the love of God, please edit your text BEFORE posting.

Comment: You're completely missing the point. Good luck anyhow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is completely impossible to do what you are asking. The only theoretical way would be, as you say - the MAC address but it is not sent in web requests.